# I can't use ANY Linux distribution because of my graphic card

Tags: video

I have a problem. On my computer I have an ATI 6800 Series and every time I try to install ANY Linux distribution I get a black screen or a white screen or sometimes i only see half of the wallpaper.

Of course this has to do with my video card. How can I solve this problem? I want to try Linux but I can't!

Comment: Try using a text-mode installer. Most distros have one. Once you have Linux installed and working in text mode, make the video card work by downloading proprietary drivers and/or tweaking your configuration.

Comment: From what I see on the nets, ATI 6800 shouldn't have any specific issues with Linux. Make sure that this is you problem and not something else. If you want to just try Linux, you can try installing any of the distros on a virtual machine, within Windows.

Comment: You can also see if you can force use of the VESA drivers. You won't get the full performance of your card, and you'll likely be unable to run it at full resolution, but at least it should *work*. As @n.m. wrote, then once you have the system running you can try to switch to a different graphics driver.

Comment: Does this happen with Live CD's too?

Comment: No, Live CD's work great.